# Replace string between two brackets and get a variable on the repleaced string

Tags: php, replace

This is my input string: (Picture will variate)

```
[image]http://picture.com/1.jpg[/image]
```

This is what i want to output:

```
<img src="http://picture.com/1.jpg">
```

How can i use preg_replace or other alternatives to do this?

Comment: You didn't put a whole lot of effort into it... https://regex101.com/r/HQCBTk/1 http://php.net/preg_replace

Comment: keywords: `bbcode` + `php` , google them, do something, and if you've some problems you can ask here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for sake of completeness, here's the `preg_replace` solution...

```
$patterns = array("/^\[image\]/", "/\[\/image\]$/");
$replacements = array("<img src=\"", "\">");

$string = "[image]http://picture.com/1.jpg[/image]";

echo preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string);
```

[Live Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4af959f8884d6ffc80bf43687f1c3e10f8a932b1)

Comment: This would fail if there are any other occurrences of `[image]` that don't follow the above format. It's not likely, but possible.

Comment: @Mike Added start and end anchors.  You know, for the case that someone is diabolical enough to name a file `[image].jpg`  :)

Comment: @PatrickQ I assumed that this was more along the lines of an article with BBCode, so it won't necessarily be at the beginning or end of the text, however the question is rather vague.

Comment: Yes, if this is in the context of a larger string, then regex in general is going to be an imperfect solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my two cents : [example on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/IxOhoS/1)

php code :

```
$s = "[image]http://picture.com/1.jpg[/image]";
$pattern = "/^\[image\](.*)\[\/image\]$/";

$result = preg_replace($pattern, '<img src="$1" />', $s);
```

Output :

> `<img src="http://picture.com/1.jpg" />`

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses preg_match and the *capture* feature of regexes.

```
$input = '[image]http://picture.com/1.jpg[/image]';
$output_pf = '<img src="%s">';

if(preg_match('#\[image\](.+)\[/image\]#', $input, $matches)) {
    $output = sprintf($output_pf, $matches[1]);
}

print $output;
```